# Controlling the number of parallel threads in the D programming language

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, d

I am learning the D language because I am interested in its support for parallelism. Here is a parallel code segment from my project:

```
import std.parallelism;


foreach (node v; taskPool.parallel(std.range.iota(z))) {
    // call here
    handle(v);
}
```

How do I control the number of threads which work in parallel? Is there an equivalent of the OpenMP function `omp_set_num_threads`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set defaultPoolThreads prior to the first use of taskPool to set the number of threads, but it won't allow you to change it on the fly.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.defaultPoolThreads

In addition, you can explicitly create new TaskPools instead of using the default. Depending on what you're trying to do, this may also be an option.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.TaskPool.this